# What is the reason for using "of" right after the verb "to be"?

Tags: word-usage

I have read a sentence like this and I wonder why the writer used "of" right after the verb "to be" Is it okay to use be+of? And what did he mean by using like this?

> The concept **is of** multi-storey buildings in which food crops are grown in environmentally controlled conditions.

Comment: It means that something has been said earlier in the text. And then here they are pinpointing it: The concept  concerns x, would be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence has been taken from [here](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=6CX-CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22The%20concept%20is%20of%20multi-storey%20buildings%20in%20which%20food%20crops%20are%20grown%20in%20environmentally%20controlled%20conditions%22&source=bl&ots=V-r2xLjumC&sig=538KoWAmA9DebTKfL6MBETgrGXg&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJvpKSyYPZAhVKl5AKHVxTCVsQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22The%20concept%20is%20of%20multi-storey%20buildings%20in%20which%20food%20crops%20are%20grown%20in%20environmentally%20controlled%20conditions%22&f=false).

Although the sentence is grammatically correct, I find it to be rather poor. Subject complements starting with "of" are indeed infrequent. I would have suggested changing it to:

- One such proposal is for the 'Vertical Farm', **based on the concept of** multi-storey buildings in which food crops are grown in environmentally controlled conditions.

OR

- One such proposal is for the 'Vertical Farm', **which consists of** multi-storey buildings in which food crops are grown in environmentally controlled conditions.

OR

- One such proposal is for the 'Vertical Farm', **which has been conceived of as** multi-storey buildings in which food crops are grown in environmentally controlled conditions.